# TTF files for word art like that in MS PowerPoint

Tags: android, truetype

I am trying to use [these instructions](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/localization-using-ttf-files.html) to use the concept of localisation and the use of TTF files.

But now am stuck at using TTFs.

How can I use the fonts like [these Word Art fonts](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/mw/images/wordArtDB.jpg) that are available in PowerPoint?

Alternatively, is there any other way to design these fonts? Or are there TTFs for these fonts?

Comment: A `ttf` has no color and does not bend in fancy ways. It just defines how each single character looks like. If you want colored & curved text you need to do that on your own.

Comment: do it using ? do u suggest me like using a canvas?

Comment: Yes, something like drawing them on a canvas, add color & effects etc

Comment: Can you suggest me any sample which can be found on internet or any sample that you can share for creating fonts like them?

Comment: No, but you can try to use the google :)